# Why don't we use DMA in userland for RAM-to-RAM copies?

Tags: c, memory, cpu, cpu-architecture, dma

I know that modern CPUs use DMA (through PCIe, and maybe other buses ?) to transfer data from RAM to devices, and when such command is emitted the memory (or I/O) controller handles it and the CPU is free to do other work until the controller reports that the operation has completed.

Now I ask myself why we don't use DMA for regular, memory-to-memory copies in userland programs. I know that memory is fast nowadays but the CPU spends a lot of time during various buffer copies which just happen to be sequences of instructions (mostly in C's memcpy and variants) looping with a source address and destination address, making a read operation from source and a store operation to destination, and incrementing both pointers <buffer length> times. Not only does the data have to do a roundtrip between RAM and the CPU (first for reading from source, then for writing to destination), which may make the copy slower (as RAM is not on CPU chip), but also it makes the CPU spend cycles on that iterative operation without any particular reason (the RAM could do it alone since it already contains all the necessary inputs, as a copy does not transform the data) instead of doing something else.

So my question is why don't we use DMA for regular RAM-to-RAM buffer copies ?

Such memory copy operation (here in C, naive implementation):

```
void memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) 
{  
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        ((char *)dest)[i] = ((char *)src)[i];
}
```

would become something like :

```
void memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    // Call a kernel-provided function that setup a DMA command. It is likely to convert virtual addresses to physical addresses in kernel since the RAM controller is not aware of virtual memory mappings
    int copy_token = dma_copy(dest, src, n); // This function would be O(1) since the RAM controller will handle the copy, the CPU is freed immediately after
    /* ... do some work ... */
    dma_wait_finish(copy_token); // Block the thread until the DMA controller reported a 'completed' event for the copy.
    /* do something else after the copy has finished */
}
```

I am not really into kernel programming and I guess that most kernels (Linux, BSD, Windows) have DMA API for the purpose of I/O communication, but I don't understand why we don't do that for userland programs when doing memory-to-memory copy. Here a DMA call would happen inside the libC's `memcpy` function. Would not a RAM-controller-handled buffer copy be better than classic CPU-handled copy?

Comment: Some discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521422/dma-memcpy-operation-in-linux . But your usage example is probably enough to demonstrate. You are paying the overhead of two syscalls, so this would only be worth it for large transfers. And there the speed is limited by the speed of the RAM itself. So you gain ... nothing? If you want to copy in the background, you can achieve that with threads.

Comment: In addition: some DMA controllers require buffers to be aligned. Some controllers can work with MMU, some work with physical addresses only. For big amount of data in some cases page remapping and copy-on-write looks more efficient.

Comment: In modern CPUs, the memory controllers are attached to the CPU itself, and CPU cores have the fastest access to it, faster than a separate device.  Freeing up a CPU core while a big copy happens in the background could be one use-case, but all the pages would have to be locked, or the blitter would have to be able to raise page faults to get the OS to page in or allocate memory.

Comment: And some computers don't have DMA channels independently of device controllers -- i.e. DMA is logic in the controller to allow it to request access to the memory bus.

Comment: Maybe each CPU core could have its own blitter (memcpy accelerator) to avoid the need for multiple CPUs to arbitrate for access to it as well as give it access to this core's current page tables?  Maybe exposed via a mechanism similar to out-of-order exec past x86 `rep movsb`, maybe with a mechanism that allows page faults to be raised later (otherwise Reorder Buffer capacity would stop it from getting far past).  Maybe with some way for code to check if a copy has finished or wait for the last pending copy.

Comment: Back in the day when CPUs were slow relative to memory, and we didn't have multi-core CPUs, some machines like Atari Mega 2 ST (2MiB of RAM) *did* have a so-called "blitter chip" to offload big copies, often for graphics purposes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blitter .  As well as copy, if could blend according to a mask so it could copy sprites.

Comment: There probably is a DMA controller in your PC but it's attached to the LPC bus.  PCI doesn't have a dedicated DMA controller as it uses bus mastering.  
If you were to use a PCI device to do memory-memory copy it would be limited to the bandwidth of the PCI bus which is a fraction of the CPU-memory b/w.  
Intel tried integrating one into the CPU (as I/O Acceleration Technology) but it failed due to lack of real-world benefits (https://lwn.net/Articles/162966/).
There is a device which allows you to memory copy in the background - it's called another core.

Comment: And BTW, you'd only consider this for huge `memcpy` sizes; for small copies the source and/or destination might already be hot in L1d or L2 cache of this core, and only take a few SIMD loads and stores.  But alternate strategies for memcpy based on size are already a thing, e.g. with x86 ERMSB or `movntps` cache-bypassing stores ([Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231)).  There might be more value on a low-end CPU or microcontroller without SIMD, since SIMD is helpful for CPU memcpy

Comment: @dimich For copy-on-write, when a virtual page is mapped onto a different physical page, a classical memcpy has to be made thereafter for the physical page to contain the correct data, isn't it ?

Comment: @teapot418 I don't know what operations a syscall involves and I guess it depends on the OS, but in most cases I think it's about the refreshing TLB to get kernel page map, maybe some other things relative to the page table (idk how OSes handle it), and then the rest may be O(1) right ? For a memcpy, we have O(n) complexity of RAM fetching, however the roundtrip complexity may be greatly reduced by L1-L2 caching which I forgot about when writing my question, so yeah maybe it would be advantageous only for big memcpys. As for "achieve that with threads": it's still the CPU who does the job

Comment: Let's have a ballpark estimate: assuming DDR4 speeds and 500 ns syscall overhead, the two syscalls cost the same as copying 15 kilobytes. If you are doing lots of much larger copying, maybe it would be worth considering a way to avoid that altogether with some clever data structures or mmap magic or something.

Comment: @endyx Sure, it is. I meant not memcpy-specific but how copying is implemented in some functional languages.